# Getting TD width in IE9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm having trouble getting the correct TD width in IE9, the following code works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE10:

```
var calculatedWidth = $(td).get(0).clientWidth - parseInt($(td).css("padding-left")) - parseInt($(td).css("padding-right"));
```

Searched the internet for quite some time, but cant seem to find a fitting solutions. The table does not have a fixed set of columns and the columns can also vary in width.

Comment: does `$('td:eq(0)').width()` not work?

Comment: `$(td).outerWidth()` -- you're welcome! http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth